# Power issues Foxconn Barebones kit

Tags: power, reboot, barebone

I have a Foxconn R20D2 bought about a year and a half ago. It ran fine for a while and then around last summer it started having power issues. I chalked it up to changes in electric current due to the overwhelmed grid when people turn on their AC units, but this problem has stayed for all year, shutting off randomly, shutting off when i turn on a vacuum and similar problems. Now that its summer again, the box basically sits there all day cycling itself, and now has gotten to the point it tried to boot and after 3 seconds, fails, shuts off and tried again.

I know its power related, it runs opensuse linux and there are never any shutdown logs or anything of that sort. As the weather got hotter i noticed it happening more and more, and it most often happened in the morning, i presume as people woke up and turn on the AC.

The power supply is a Chennel well technology co LTD model DSL-150. 150W max output. 
Its an intel atom dual core, with 2 sata drives, no CD/floppy etc, recently upgrades from 2 to 4gb of ram.

It runs at 104 degrees Fahrenheit all the time almost.

Any way i can test the power supply or anything else to try to fix it? Im a software guy, not hardware so im at a complete loss here, thanks for all assistance you can provide!

EDIT: The switch on the back that says 230 or 115 is set to 230. If im in the USA, could that be causing the problems?

Comment: "*If im in the USA*" - Why the conditional?  Aren't you sure where you are?

Comment: I honestly didn't think a think about voltage until i did research today, the conditional is actually attached to the rest of the statement. $that = switch being set to 230; If(I live in the USA){is $that causing problems? } else { what is?}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the USA, it should be set at 115 and not 220 or 230 (Europe). I have had no experience with what happens when you have something greater than 115 set.

You can use a power supply tester to check the PSU, there are several out there but I like the Antec Digital PC Power Tester... though it is pricey ($40 usd)

Comment: "*what happens when you have something greater than 115 set*" - If the input is about 115 Volts but the PSU is set to convert for 220/240V, then the output voltage is cut in half.  Americans are lucky; 240V users can damage their equipment set to the wrong (low) input voltage.  Premium equipment have *universal power supplies* that auto-detect the input voltage.